# How to put the database values in an array in controller in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a table named Scope in my databse, This table has two columns: ScopeName ad ScopeID. How can I pass all the data of ScopeName column to my controller and put them in an array? after that I want to show the content in a dropdown list in my view. Thanks

Comment: How are you currently getting data out of your db? What have you tried?

Comment: I'm using Database First approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can get ahold of an `IQueryable<Scope>` from your database, this LINQ code should work:

```
var scopeNames = (from s in DB.GetScopes()
                 select s.ScopeName).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Now how can I show this array in a dropdown list in my view?

Answer (score 2):

following @Charmander answer..

To pass the data to the view you can do this:

In your controller create a `SelectList` with your array and pass it to your view:

```
ViewBag.myList = new SelectList(scopeNames);
```

Then in your view, use Html.DropDownlist:

```
@Html.DropDownList("myList", String.Empty)
```